# How to splice every 0th index particular key "logic" & value of a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops

I have a nested object and I want to find the splice every 0th index key "logic" & value in it. Let's say object looks like this:

Original input:

```
[
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "122",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "123",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "otp"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "< Less than",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "logic": "AND",
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "logic": "AND",
            "parameter": "Amount",
            "condition": "< Less than",
            "value": "12",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  }
]
```

Code:

```
for(var i=0;i〈conditionItem.length;i++)
    {
      // conditionItem[0].splice(conditionItem.indexOf(logic), 1);


      // console.log("ccc=",conditionItem)
      if(Array.isArray(conditionItem[i].condition))
      {
        var conditionItem1=[];
        for(var j=0;j〈conditionItem.length;j++)
        {
          if(j==0)
          {
            conditionItem1.push({"condition":conditionItem[j].condition,"level":conditionItem[j].level,"parameter":conditionItem[j].parameter,"type":conditionItem[j].type,"value":conditionItem[j].value})
          }else{
            conditionItem1.push(conditionItem[j])
          }

        }
        conditionItem[i].condition = conditionItem1;        
      }

    }
    console.log("conditionItem::=",conditionItem);

for(var i=0;i〈conditionItem.length;i++)
    {
      // conditionItem[0].splice(conditionItem.indexOf(logic), 1);


      // console.log("ccc=",conditionItem)
      if(Array.isArray(conditionItem[i].condition))
      {
        var conditionItem1=[];
        for(var j=0;j〈conditionItem.length;j++)
        {
          if(j==0)
          {
            conditionItem1.push({"condition":conditionItem[j].condition,"level":conditionItem[j].level,"parameter":conditionItem[j].parameter,"type":conditionItem[j].type,"value":conditionItem[j].value})
          }else{
            conditionItem1.push(conditionItem[j])
          }

        }
        conditionItem[i].condition = conditionItem1;        
      }

    }
    console.log("conditionItem::=",conditionItem);
```

expected output:

```
[
  {
    "conditions": [
      {

        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "122",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {

            "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "123",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "otp"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "< Less than",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  },
  {
    "conditions": [
      {

        "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
        "condition": "Equals",
        "value": "12",
        "level": "first",
        "type": "condition"
      },
      {
        "level": "second",
        "type": "group",
        "nextChildLogic": "AND",
        "conditions": [
          {

            "parameter": "Amount",
            "condition": "< Less than",
            "value": "12",
            "level": "second",
            "type": "condition"
          }
        ],
        "groupLogic": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Every condition is an object, not an array. You can simply [remove the `logic` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object).

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant and short way I could think of is using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and some recursion:

```
// setting a default empty array in case the *initial* object has no condition key
const parseData = ({ conditions = [], ...rest }) => {
  const cond = conditions.map(({ logic, ...condition }) => {
    if (condition.conditions) {
      return parseData(condition);
    }
    return condition;
  });

  return {
    conditions: cond,
    ...rest
  };
};
```

#### Breakdown:

1. iterating over each element
2. [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (extracting) `conditions` while keeping the rest under `rest`
3. iterating over the extracted `conditions`
4. extracting `logic` the same way we did in #2
5. if our condition has its own conditions - we'll call parseData again, otherwise - returning a new object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) combined with `conditions` minus the extracted `logic` along with everything **not** conditions which we previously extracted into `rest`

An important note pointed out by @3limin4t0r:  the object rest destruction assignment is currently still a stage 3 proposal.
It's already has support from the major browsers, however the spec might change.
Here are some thoughts on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150001/1194694

#### A working example:

```js
const data = [ { "conditions": [ { "logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "122", "level": "first", "type": "condition" }, { "level": "second", "type": "group", "nextChildLogic": "AND", "conditions": [ { "logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "123", "level": "second", "type": "condition" } ], "groupLogic": "AND" } ], "modeOfAuth": "otp" }, { "conditions": [ { "logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "< Less than", "value": "12", "level": "first", "type": "condition" } ], "modeOfAuth": "frictionless" }, { "conditions": [ { "logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "12", "level": "first", "type": "condition" }, { "level": "second", "type": "group", "nextChildLogic": "AND", "conditions": [ { "logic": "AND", "parameter": "Amount", "condition": "< Less than", "value": "12", "level": "second", "type": "condition" } ], "groupLogic": "AND" } ], "modeOfAuth": "frictionless" } ]

const parseData = ({ conditions = [], ...rest }) => {
  const cond = conditions.map(({ logic, ...condition }) => {
    if (condition.conditions) {
      return parseData(condition);
    }
    return condition;
  });

  return {
    conditions: cond,
    ...rest
  };
};

console.log(data.map(parseData));
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the object rest destruction assignment is currently still a stage 3 proposal. [As mentioned in the documentation you linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring). Furthermore your current solution doesn't match the expected output. It doesn't remove nested `"logic"` properties. Eg. `root[0].conditions[1].conditions[0].logic` (from the input) is still present in the output.

Comment: You're absolutely right! missed out no that, sorry. Will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The thing that comes to mind is to build a recursive function that handles this. You can remove/delete properties using the `delete` keyword. Keep in mind that **this solution mutates the contents of the `data` variable**.

This solution assumes that if further conditions are added, they are in the same format as the second condition.

```js
var data = [{"conditions": [{"logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "122", "level": "first", "type": "condition"}, {"level": "second", "type": "group", "nextChildLogic": "AND", "conditions": [{"logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "123", "level": "second", "type": "condition"}], "groupLogic": "AND"}], "modeOfAuth": "otp"}, {"conditions": [{"logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "< Less than", "value": "12", "level": "first", "type": "condition"}], "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"}, {"conditions": [{"logic": "AND", "parameter": "Risk Engine Score", "condition": "Equals", "value": "12", "level": "first", "type": "condition"}, {"level": "second", "type": "group", "nextChildLogic": "AND", "conditions": [{"logic": "AND", "parameter": "Amount", "condition": "< Less than", "value": "12", "level": "second", "type": "condition"}], "groupLogic": "AND"}], "modeOfAuth": "frictionless"}];

function updateConditions(conditions) {
  // guard against empty arrays
  if (!conditions.length) return;

  // split the conditions into head and tail
  var [head, ...tail] = conditions;

  // remove the logic property
  delete head.logic;

  // update tail conditions
  tail.forEach(condition => updateConditions(condition.conditions));
}

data.forEach(obj => updateConditions(obj.conditions));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: If the logic for a property gets more complicated, consider moving the logic to a separate function `function updateCondition(condition) { /* ... */ }` then replace `delete head.logic;` with `updateCondition(head);`.

Comment: You might like to add that this will cause the original object to mutate, in which case it might change for all elements that hold a reference to it.